# Rake Preview not working in Octopress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, octopress

I have ruby version 1.9.3 installed on my machine and working on an octopress project for my personal website.

I used rvm for my gems and followed all the steps documented by octopress.org. But I found some errors in my rake server. Here is my command log.

```
Tin-Aung-Linn:octopress tal$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
Tin-Aung-Linn:octopress tal$ rake generate
## Generating Site with Jekyll
identical source/stylesheets/screen.css 
Configuration from /Users/tal/Sites/mysite.com/octopress/_config.yml
Building site: source -> public/github
Successfully generated site: source -> public/github
Tin-Aung-Linn:octopress tal$ rake preview
Starting to watch source with Jekyll and Compass. Starting Rack on port 4000
Configuration from /Users/tal/Sites/mysite.com/octopress/_config.yml
[2013-07-04 14:50:23] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-07-04 14:50:23] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
[2013-07-04 14:50:23] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=51669 port=4000
Auto-regenerating enabled: source -> public/github
[2013-07-04 14:50:23] regeneration: 112 files changed
>>> Change detected at 14:50:23 to: screen.scss
identical public/github/stylesheets/screen.css 

Dear developers making use of FSSM in your projects,
FSSM is essentially dead at this point. Further development will
be taking place in the new shared guard/listen project. Please
let us know if you need help transitioning! ^_^b
- Travis Tilley

>>> Compass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jul/2013 14:50:34] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 - 0.0208
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jul/2013 14:50:34] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 - 0.0015
^C
[2013-07-04 14:50:41] INFO  going to shutdown ...
Tin-Aung-Linn:octopress tal$
```

Anyone helps me.
Tin Aung Linn

Comment: There are no errors there - only a warning that octopress uses a now unmaintained library

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jul/2013 14:50:34] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 - 0.0015

While showing this , I flip back to my browser nothing show at http://localhost:4000.

Comment: Is there an index file to show ? check the generated files to see what has been generated

Comment: Generated index is ok theoretically in public/mysite and _deploy/. It is about Rack and Campass I think . Now trying to write a simple application which use rack and Campass.

Comment: Mine is showing Compass is polling .. may be there are different. interesting article at Github. https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/394

Comment: if the generated index is in public/mysite then you'd have to hit localhost:4000/mysite to see the files

Comment: Did you press Ctr + C ( just curious saw in your command ) ? You have to let it running and check first.

Comment: @FrederickCheung thanks you so much ! I solved it with your guide. That last line you wrote saved me. localhost:4000/mysite :happy thanks Ko WMS also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by @Frederick's comment and closed this thread.

Answer

> if the generated index is in public/mysite then you'd have to hit
>   localhost:4000/mysite to see the files –

Comment: I started having this problem too, perhaps due to upgrading to mavericks.  I just run http-server (installed from npm) in the _deploy directory and it works.  Any dev http server should do.