# Octopress FSSM Issue Rake preview

Tags: rake, blogs, preview, octopress, fssm

Hey guys I am currently running an octopress blog and unfortunately I ran into a FSSM dead message, I tried options such as [Octopress failed on running rake preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751377/octopress-failed-on-running-rake-preview) and this [Rake Preview not working in Octopress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465404/rake-preview-not-working-in-octopress)
and many others. I still get this however whenever I try to run rake preview.

```
$rake preview
## Set the codepage to 65001 for windows machines
Starting to watch source with Jekyll and Compass. Starting Rack on port 4000
Configuration from C:/Users/Welcome/Documents/GitHub/octopress/_config.yml

>>> Change detected at 10:11:01 to: screen.scss
Auto-regenerating enabled: source -> public
[2014-05-07 10:11:01] regeneration: 93 files changed
Thin web server <v1.6.2 codename Doc Brown>
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:4000, CTRL+C to stop
identical public/stylesheets/screen.css 

Dear developers making use of FSSM in your projects,
FSSM is essentially dead at this point. Further development will
be taking place in the new shared guard/listen project. Please
let us know if you need help transitioning! ^_^b
- Travis Tilley
```

Help would be appreciated